# How to remove attribute found within a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
var $imageSelected = '<div style="position: absolute"><span>hello</span></div>';
```

I need to remove the style attribute form the created variable

I tried:

```
$imageSelected + "*").removeAttr("style");
```

and

```
$imageSelected).find("*").removeAttr("style");
```

*Full code with added **replace** functionality as **per first answer**:*

```
$(".grid-item").on("click", function() {
  var $imageSelected = $(this).prop('outerHTML');
  var $paste = $imageSelected.replace(/style.+"/, '');
  $('#usp-custom-4').val(function(_, currentValue) {
    return currentValue + $paste
  });
});
```

Using `$imageSelected).removeAttr("style");` doesn't work and by using the code above it does remove style yet it is pasting many times the code into the text area, not `this` clicked only

> $('#usp-custom-4') is the textarea id

Comment: What is $imageSelected ?

Comment: you don't need the find part. Just removeAttr against the $(..)

Comment: $($imageSelected).removeAttr("style");

Comment: @epascarello that doesn't work

Comment: Well what else are you doing with that code....??? Code does not show you actually working with the variable after the attribute is removed.

Comment: `var $imageSelected = '<div style="position: absolute"><span>hello</span></div>';
var x = $($imageSelected).removeAttr("style");
console.log(x.attr("style"))` looks okay to me...

Comment: @epascarello Isn't `$` sign refer to the DOM objects only?

Comment: exactly it should be $imageSelected.removeAttr("style"); yet it isn't working in my case

Comment: Makes no sense that you are setting value.... So you setting HTML mark up into a textarea??

Comment: You need to *select*  an element to perform `removeAttr` function.In this case it's just a string var.

Comment: @epascarello yes I am, yet that element is coming into the textarea with the style attribute and also each time i click it adds many div not this clicked only i'm afraid

Comment: What is the `$('#usp-custom-4')` element? Are you sure that you want to insert the result as it's value?

Comment: $('#usp-custom-4') is the textarea id

Comment: I ran it above and it worked fine....

Comment: You want to insert a HTML object into the textarea? What's the point?

Comment: because i am sending that textarea value in php to generate an html page later, this textarea will be hidden anyway @Kinduser

Comment: Well, if only there's nothing wrong with the function inside `val()`, it should work fine imo. `$paste` variable holds exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use e.g. `replace` function.

```js
var $myValue = '<div style="position: absolute"><span>hello</span></div>';

    $myValue = $myValue.replace(/ style.+"/, '');
    console.log($myValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

Clone, remove attr, select the html

```js
$(".grid-item").on("click", function() {
  var $imageSelected = $(this).clone().removeAttr("style"),
      code = $("<div></div>").append($imageSelected).html();
      //code = $imageSelected.prop('outerHTML');
  $('#usp-custom-4').val(function(_, currentValue) {
    return currentValue + code
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 1em; border: 1px solid black; margin: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-item" style="display:block;">1</div>
<div class="grid-item" style="display:block;">2</div>
<div class="grid-item" style="display:block;">3</div>
<div class="grid-item" style="display:block;">4</div>

<textarea id="usp-custom-4"></textarea>
```

Comment: this works too actually. yet i am having the inserted item repeated each time i click

Comment: maybe i should be appending